# C++ function errors

Tags: c++, cmd

Error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'float')
heres the function it appears in.

this is my first time working with pointers, stay tuned for further derps

```
 void printArray(float *array, int hours)
{
    int x = hours;
    cout << "Number of hours each student spent : " << endl;

    for (x = 0; x <= size; x++)
    {
        cout << *array[x] << "  " << endl;
                    ^^ Error is here
    }
}
```

second error is -- invalid tyoes 'int[int]' for array subscript
found in this function

```
    void getFBTData(int size, int hours)
{
    for (int count = 0; count < size; count++)
    {
        cout << "Enter number if hours each student spent.  " << count + 1;
        cin >> hours[count];
                    ^^ Error is here
    }
    cin.sync();
}
```

Comment: Think about what you're doing.  `hours` and `count` are both `int` - what do you expect `hours[count]` to do?

Comment: trying troubleshoot my project. #GoofyBall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you really need to learn how to dereference and subscript. Some basic rules:

```
cout << *array[x] << "  " << endl; //same as *(array[x]), cannot derefence float
         array[x] //change to

cin >> hours[count]; //hours is int, cannot subscript

void getFBTData(int size, int *hours) //change to pointer
```